# How to view datetime stamp for history command in Zsh shell

Tags: zsh, command-history

When I run the history command on my ubuntu server, I get output as follows:

```
   history
   ...
   25  cd ~
   26  ls -a
   27  vim /etc/gitconfig
   28  vim ~/.gitconfig
```

I want to view the datetime of a particular user. However when I assume them:

```
su otheruser
export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T  '
history
...
25  cd ~
26  ls -a
27  vim /etc/gitconfig
28  vim ~/.gitconfig
```

It still doesn't show datetime. I am using zsh shell.

Comment: I created a dedicated program for storing and viewing your history, maybe of interest: https://github.com/chrissound/MoscoviumOrange.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski is your program haskel-based? I am on ubuntu, how can I install it and what advantages do I have with your program?

Comment: Probably best to create an issue on there if you need help with installation. Advantages are logging the path, better search functionality, color highlighting and not shell dependent.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

I believe the HISTTIMEFORMAT is for Bash shells. If you're using `zsh` then you could use these switches to the `history` command:

#### Examples

```
$ history -E
    1   2.12.2013 14:19  history -E
```

[Alternatively](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/739): `\history -E`

```
$ history -i
    1  2013-12-02 14:19  history -E
```

[Alternatively](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/739): `\history -i`

```
$ history -D
    1  0:00  history -E
    2  0:00  history -i
```

If you do a `man zshoptions` or `man zshbuiltins` you can find out more information about these switches as well as other info related to `history`.

*excerpt from zshbuiltins man page*

```
Also when listing,
  -d     prints timestamps for each command
  -f     prints full time-date stamps in the US `MM/DD/YY hh:mm' format
  -E     prints full time-date stamps in the European `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm' format
  -i     prints full time-date stamps in ISO8601 `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm' format
  -t fmt prints time and date stamps in the given format; fmt is formatted 
         with the strftime function with the  zsh extensions described for 
         the %D{string} prompt format in the section EXPANSION OF PROMPT 
         SEQUENCES in zshmisc(1).  The resulting formatted string must be no 
         more than 256 characters or will not be printed.
  -D     prints elapsed times; may be combined with one of the options above.
```

#### Debugging invocation

You can use the following 2 methods to debug `zsh` when you invoke it.

**Method #1**

```
$ zsh -xv
```

**Method #2**

```
$ zsh
$ setopt XTRACE VERBOSE
```

In either case you should see something like this when it starts up:

```
$ zsh -xv
#
# /etc/zshenv is sourced on all invocations of the
# shell, unless the -f option is set.  It should
# contain commands to set the command search path,
# plus other important environment variables.
# .zshenv should not contain commands that produce
# output or assume the shell is attached to a tty.
#

#
# /etc/zshrc is sourced in interactive shells.  It
# should contain commands to set up aliases, functions,
# options, key bindings, etc.
#

## shell functions
...
...
unset -f pathmunge _src_etc_profile_d
+/etc/zshrc:49> unset -f pathmunge _src_etc_profile_d

# Created by newuser for 4.3.10
```

Comment: "event not found: -i " "event not found: -E". Do I need to load something in a config file before running these switches?

Comment: Are you sure you're in a `zsh`? I'm using a vanilla `zsh` that I run and it has them.

Comment: ps -p $$
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
23771 pts/4    00:00:00 zsh

Comment: What version of `zsh`? `zsh --version`. I just confirmed on Ubuntu 12.10 that the commands I gave you worked just fine.

Comment: zsh 4.3.17 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)

Comment: you need the `extendedhistory` option enabled for timestamps of commands to be saved in your HISTFILE.

Comment: @JohnMerlino I had zsh 4.3.10 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) on a server for which I wanted to view history with timestamps. After looking through the `zshbuiltins` man page, I discovered that I needed to use `fc`. What finally worked for me was `fc -li`. You can pass command numbers to `fc`, too, so `fc -li -100` lists the last 100 commands in your history.

Comment: I have to use `\history -E`, I use oh-my-zsh

Comment: you can set it permanently in oh-my-zsh by uncommenting this line in your personal .zshrc: HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

Comment: @juanpastas, that works.. any idea why?

Comment: It's a long-standing (6+ years) bug with oh-my-zsh, see this issue on github: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/739

Comment: @juanpastas fix is not needed anymore for newer oh-my-zsh versions. Check `which history`, it should return `aliased to omz_history`.

Comment: @sites I also use omz, but no \ needed. Maybe they changed this.

Comment: In `man history` I did not find these flags E, i and D. [In the Bash History Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-History-Builtins) neither.Thanks for the info with zshoptions, what is the D Flag for?

Answer (score 25):

`history -E` or `history -i` or whatever **DO NOT** work for me.

`zsh --version` shows that `zsh 4.3.6 (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)`.

Then `fc -li 100` works! It shows the recent 100 commands with timestamp :)

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me as well, contrary to the top answer. My version is: `zsh 5.1.1 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)`. And while I'm here: do you know how to get the help of the command `fc`? Neither `man fc` nor `fc --help` work

Comment: @exhuma why not google it :)

Comment: @Gab是好人 do you have history aliased? if you are using `oh-my-zsh` the history command is add the `-l` flag in one of the options. see https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/lib/history.zsh#L10-L15

Comment: `fc -lf` will show a full timestamp.  Note that this works only on zsh, not on bash.

Comment: @exhuma In zsh, you can use `run-help fc`.

Comment: `fc`'s documentation is available in zsh's info manual. The info manual can be accessed via `info zsh`. The specific heading to look under is `Shell Builtin Commands`.

Comment: @exhuma On my system I can see the man page for the zsh commands with `man zshbuiltins`.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using `oh-my-zsh` addon in `zsh`, `history -E` or `history -i` wont work (because it's aliased to `fc -l 1`).

As @juanpastas pointed out, try

`\history -E`

or

`\history -i`

or

`fc -li 100`

Comment: I just added: 'alias history="fc -li 1"' to redefine the history alias into my ~/.zshrc file and it's now working as desired!

Comment: or even better: 'alias history="history -i". That way you can run the same command in the alias, and if you want to add more keys/options it is not that confusing.

Comment: history in `omz` is aliased to `omz_history` which uses `fc (-l) $@`, [here](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/lib/history.zsh) and not `fc -l 1` but maybe `1` means show all entries.

Comment: Seems that `fc -li 99` means "show history from entry 99" and without a numeric arg, it show only the last 16(?) or so. Try `fc -li 1 | wc -l` to see how many are available.