# Z Shell History doesn't show timestamps with HISTTIMEFORMAT

Tags: zsh, command-history, macos

I'm trying to add timestamps to my history output. I am running Z Shell on a Mac (Monterey v12.2).

I have the following in my `.zprofile` regarding history.

```
export HISTSIZE=5000
export HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history
export SAVEHIST=5000
export HISTFILESIZE=5000
export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '
setopt appendhistory
alias hist="history 1"
```

I know my `.zprofile` is being loaded since other variables and `alias` statements are working. However my history does *not* include any timestamp currently.

It looks like this:

```
$ hist
 1008  ls -lah
 1009  npm install
 1010  clear
 1011  git status
 1012  npm install
 1013  npm start
 1014  clear
 1015  git status
 1016  vim .gitignore
 1017  git status
 1018  git add .gitignore
```

How can I make sure my `history` makes use of the `HISTTIMEFORMAT`?

Comment: afaik `HISTTIMEFORMAT` is specific to bash - see for example [How to view datetime stamp for history command in Zsh shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103398/how-to-view-datetime-stamp-for-history-command-in-zsh-shell)

Answer (score 0):

If you want `history` (same as `fc -l`) to display timestamps according to a strftime-like format stored in the `$HISTTIMEFORMAT` variable, you need to call it with `-t "$HISTTIMEFORMAT"`:

```
alias 'hist=fc -lt "$HISTTIMEFORMAT" 1'
```